# Probability of Achieving a Certain Score or Greater in Test with Penalty Marking

Tags: probability, statistics

Say that a multiple choice test consists of $n$ questions, each with 5 possible answers. One answer is correct and worth 1 mark if selected. Incorrect answers carry a penalty of a quarter mark. What are the chances of attaining a certain score or better purely by guessing every question?

My first thought would have been to do this by integration, but I am not proficient enough to come up with an equation to integrate in the first place. Is there an easier way?

P.S. if deriving an expression in terms of $n$ is more difficult than is worth bothering about, then the number of questions that happens to fit my real-life scenario is 100.

Comment: Can't you just consider that you start with $-n/4$ points, every wrong question is worth $0$ points, and every right question $5/4$? Then you can just rescalate everything

Comment: Alternative:  The probability of getting exactly $~k~$ questions correct is $~\displaystyle f(n,k) = \binom{n}{k} k^{1/5}(n-k)^{4/5},~$ and this gives a score of $M(n,k) = \displaystyle (k \times 1) - \frac{n-k}{4}.~$ So, the probability of scoring $~M(n,k)~$ or higher equals $\displaystyle \sum_{r = k}^n f(n,r).$

Comment: For $100$ questions, a Normal approximation should work well.  What is the mean and variance of the score of a single question?